# Simulating data in R for poor planning

Tags: r, dplyr, simulation

I'm trying to estimate the effect of poor planning on an ecoms business. I have 2 different warehouses and one cost much more than the other. In a perfect situation, we always pick the cheapest price however, the process isn't perfect and sometimes some of the orders are bought from the wrong warehouse.

In order to test how much we could be losing I'm developing a simulation model to test 3 scenarios. These are the following:

1. Pick the cheapest warehouse everytime
2. 10% of the orders are bought at the wrong price
3. 25% of the orders are bought at the wrong price

I'm currently at a loss of where to start, I know that my data need to fit a normal distribution and I need to simulate the 2nd and 3rd scenarios many times as each will give different results.

```
structure(list(Customer = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), `Option 1` = c(5, 
100, 107, 400, 30), `Option 2` = c(19, 200, 50, 300, 70), `Probability Selecting the more expensive option` = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Customer `Option 1` `Option 2` `Probability Selecting the more expensive option`
  <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>                                             <dbl>
1 a                 5         19                                               0.1
2 b               100        200                                               0.1
3 c               107         50                                               0.1
4 d               400        300                                               0.1
5 e                30         70                                               0.1
```

Any help on how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you use `sample` weighted with the probability of picking from each column using the argument `prob=`?

Comment: I would *not* expect a Normal distribution, as that suggests a symmetric (and asymptotic) distribution; can the wrong price be less expensive than the cheapest warehouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if I understand correctly, I might go about it like this:

```
library(dplyr)

#I've renamed the columns to be easier to work with
df <- structure(list(customer = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                     op1 = c(5, 100, 107, 400, 30),
                     op2 = c(19, 200, 50, 300, 70), 
                     probs = c(0.1,  0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df


# Here is a simple dplyr solution to getting your best and worst selection to chose from 
df <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(best = min(c(op1, op2)),
         worst = max(c(op1, op2)))


# this function repeatedly samples from the best and worst option with a probability of the argument probs
# it is deendent on integer indexing so if you move or add columns the function will need adjusting
# it can also be adjusted to use the prob of each row if that were to change through time
# The output is a matrix with the number of rwplicates as columns
# order of probability is best worst so probs = c(0.4,0.6) means it is less likely to choose best
resample_func <- function(df, reps = 5, probs = c(0.4,0.6)) {
  mat <- matrix(nrow = nrow(df), ncol = reps)
  nc <- df[, c(5,6)]
  # print(nc)
  
  for (j in 1:ncol(mat)) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      # nc <- df[,c(2,3)]
      mat[i, j] <- t(sample(nc[i,], 1, replace = F, prob = probs))
    }
  }
  rownames(mat) <- df$customer
  colnames(mat) <- paste0("rep_", 1:ncol(mat))
  return(mat)
}

resample_func(df)
```

Please check the output carefully! Let me know if this is what you were after :)
Also see @r2evans comment

Comment: Thanks @QAsena that was very helpful!